# c# linq, sum distinct values by index

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have multiple List with multiple values that may or may not have the same number of items..
I need to add up only the numbers for a distinct name by index..

heres some code to help explain...

```
    public static List<p> pList= new List<p>();
    public class p
    {
        public string name;
        public double sum;
        public List<double> ip;
    }
```

So, I have class "p", as a list..
some of the names in class "p" will be same and some different..

I need to sum the values in "ip" by index for only the class "p" that has the same name..

Data Example..

```
name = a, sum = 10, ip = {2,2,2,2,2}    
name = a, sum = 10, ip = {0,0,5,5}    
name = a, sum = 5, ip = {0,0,5}    
name = b, sum = 20, ip = {0,20}    
name = b, sum = 10, ip = {10}
```

Result..

```
name = a, sum = 25, ip = {2,2,12,7,2}    
name = b, sum = 30, ip = {10,20}
```

Below is the code I have already written..

```
List<p> distinctmerge = pList
                         .GroupBy(t => t.name)
                         .Select(g => new p
                         {
                             name = g.Select(a => a.name).FirstOrDefault(),
                             sum = g.Sum(a => a.sum),
                             ip = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3 }
                         }).ToList();
```

The part I cant figure out is here..

```
ip = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can sum up the ip list by

```
 ip = Enumerable.Range(0, g.Select(a => a.ip.Length).Max()).Select(idx => g.Select(a => a.ip.ElementAtOrDefault(idx)).Sum()).ToList()
```

Comment: Good. In the last part you can benefit from `.ElementAtOrDefault(idx)`.

Comment: Thanks, going to try it.. I kept looking online and seen something kind of like this but just could not figure it out..

Comment: Awesome.. I spent hours trying to figure this out.. I should of came here earlier.. haha

My Finaly code was just slightly different..    ip = Enumerable.Range(0, g.Select(a => a.ip.Count).Max()).Select(idx => g.Select(a => a.ip.Count > idx ? a.ip[idx] : 0).Sum()).ToList()

had to use Count instead because its a List, and changed a[idx] to a.ip[idx]

Comment: This won't compile. It must be `a.ip.Count()` since it is a `List<double>` not a `double[]`.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using `SelectMany` and `GroupBy`:

```
        List<p> distinctmerge = pList
            .GroupBy(t => t.name)
            .Select(g => new p
            {
                name = g.Select(a => a.name).FirstOrDefault(),
                sum = g.Sum(a => a.sum),
                ip = g.SelectMany(a => a.ip.Select((e, i) => new { e, i }))
                      .GroupBy(a => a.i)
                      .OrderBy(a => a.Key)
                      .Select(a => a.Sum(e => e.e))
                      .ToList()
            }).ToList();
```